# JQuery AJAX not working in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I tried integrating the autocomplete from here : http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/ , but it doesn't seem to work. Here is what i have tried so far:

I am currently at the url  localhost:8000/movie

In urls.py I have added

```
url(r'^movie/get_Name$',views.get_Name,name='get_Name'),
```

In views.py I have added a function get_Name. For the sake of testing, i have made it simple .

```
def get_Name(request):
    '''This view is for autocompleting - see tutorial at 
    http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/'''


    q = request.GET.get('term', '')

    results = []
    results = [
    {
    "id":'abc',
    "label":'abc',
    "value":'abc'
    },
    {
    "id":'xyz',
    "label":'xyz',
    "value":'xyz'
    }
    ]

    data = json.dumps(results)

    mimetype = 'application/json'

    return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

I have an input field in my template

```
<form action="/movie/do_something/" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="ui-widget">
<label for="Name">Name: </label>
<input id="Name" type="text" name="Name" maxlength="100">
</div>


I have also included the 3 files mentioned in the link (I somehow cannot paste it here on SO)
```

and the script

```
 <script> 


    $(function() {
      $("#Name").autocomplete({
        source: "/movie/get_Name/",
        minLength: 2,
      });
    });

</script>
```

The autocomplete isn't still working . Any thoughts ?

Edit :
This is what i get in console

```
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /movie/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8913
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /static/css/navbar-static-top.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /static/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /static/js/bootstrap.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /static/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[02/Aug/2015 11:06:13]"GET /static/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
```

Comment: 1. Does the server side get the request? 2. Do you have JS error? 3. Is movie is an app?

Comment: Yes, movie is an app (I haven't made a urls.py for the app though).Edited my question for console. I get these lines when I land at localhost:8000/movie , but when i type something in search box , nothing happens over console.

Comment: use `JsonResponse` or specify *kwarg* `content_type` to `HttpResponse` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects